# Session timeout warning message doesn't work properly on mobile browsers

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, session, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I'm using a plugin (https://github.com/orangehill/bootstrap-session-timeout) to implement session timeout feature. A warning message will be showing before session expires.

It's working well on desktop browsers, but not working properly on mobile browsers in some cases.

I have multiple tabs (Bootstrap tab) sharing the same jsp file (main.jsp) and the same session timeout scripts.

This feature is working fine on the first tab, NOT working on the others.

I tried to refresh the page after session timeout interval. The session already expired, but the warning message was not showing.

Below is the session timeout JS script used to show prompt message before the session expires

```
$.sessionTimeout({
    message:'Please be aware that your session will soon expire if you remain idle longer than ' + t + ' minutes.',
    keepAliveUrl:'<c:url value="/rest/keep-alive"/>',
    logoutUrl:'<c:url value="/logout"/>',
    redirUrl:'<c:url value="/redirect"/>',
    warnAfter: (parseInt($('#sessionTimeoutInterval').val(), 10) - 660) *1000,
    redirAfter: (parseInt($('#sessionTimeoutInterval').val(), 10) - 60) *1000
});
```

Any ideas for this?

Comment: I suspect this is because mobile browsers suspend JS execution and timers in tabs that are not foreground (to save battery).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Is there any reference or workaround for that?